# To get the data attribute if a checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have made a form to get `value` and `data-cat` from that form if checkbox is checked. Thanks to stackoverflow, I have achieve to get the values of form but cannot get a satisfying answer to achieve data attribute from `jquery`.

Html:

```
<div class="price-col-title-wrap">
                <h4>Immer enthalten</h4>
                <!-- <h3><span>CHF</span> <span id="immer-total">0</span>.-</h3> -->
                  <input type="checkbox" id="c1" class="immer" value="50" data-cat="Installation Wordpress" name="cc" onclick="return false" checked/>
                  <label for="c1"><span> </span> Installation Wordpress</label> <br/>

                  <input type="checkbox" id="c2" class="immer" value="50" data-cat="Basis SEO und Dynamic Sitemap" name="cc"/>
                  <label for="c2"><span> </span>  Basis SEO und Dynamic Sitemap</label> <br/>

                  <input type="checkbox" id="c3" class="immer" value="50" data-cat="Adresse, Öffungszeiten, Telefon mit Call-Funktion für mobil" name="cc"/>
                  <label for="c3"><span> </span> Adresse, Öffungszeiten, Telefon mit Call-Funktion für mobil</label> <br/>

                  <input type="checkbox" id="c4" class="immer" value="50" data-cat="Seite für Datenschutz und Impressum" name="cc"/>
                  <label for="c4"><span> </span> Seite für Datenschutz und Impressum</label> <br/>

                  <input type="checkbox" id="c5" class="immer" value="50" data-cat="Social Media Follow (FB, G+, Twitter)" name="cc"/>
                  <label for="c5"><span> </span> Social Media Follow (FB, G+, Twitter)</label> <br/>

                  <input type="checkbox" id="c6" class="immer" value="50" data-cat="Kontaktformular + Google Map API" name="cc"/>
                  <label for="c6"><span> </span> Kontaktformular + Google Map API</label> <br/>
                  <h3><span>CHF</span> <span id="immer-total">0</span>.-</h3>
                    <input id="input" type="text" value="0"/>
                    <textarea id="t"></textarea>
          </div>
```

I have a jquery to achieve the values from every checkbox but there's another attribute `data-cat` which contain a unique name for each checkbox. 
My problem is to list the checked `data-cat` in the `textarea` whose `id=t`

upto now the js I am using is:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('immer'),
        total  = document.getElementById('immer-total');
 for (var i=0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        inputs[i].onchange = function() {
      var add = this.value * (this.checked ? 1 : -1);
           total.innerHTML = parseFloat(total.innerHTML) + add
             var new_total = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input').value);
  console.log(new_total);
    document.getElementById('input').value=new_total + add

        }
    }
```

This is used to get the values from every checkbox

And after lots of query in stackoverflow I get a js to get the `attribute`

```
function updateTextArea() {     
     var cats = $('.immer').map(function(){
return this.dataset.cat
// or $(this).attr('data-cat')
}).get()
 }


 $(function() {
   $('#price-col-title-wrap input').click(updateTextArea);
   updateTextArea();
  });
```

But it didn't help me. How can I get the `data-cat` in that `textarea`.

[you can view it on my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sus_hill/wx2dmLkn/2/)

Comment: `$(this).data('cat')`

Comment: @freedomn-m It didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do:-

```
function updateTextArea() {
  var cats = $('.immer').map(function() {
    return $(this).data('cat');
  }).get();

  console.log(cats);
}
```

Returns in console:-

```
["Installation Wordpress", "Basis SEO und Dynamic Sitemap", "Adresse, Öffungszeiten, Telefon mit Call-Funktion für mobil", "Seite für Datenschutz und Impressum", "Social Media Follow (FB, G+, Twitter)", "Kontaktformular + Google Map API"]
```

To get the checked checbox data in textarea, you can do:

```
$('.immer').change(function() {
  $('#t').val(this.checked ? $(this).data('cat') : '');
});
```

Comment: @palasH thanks for your ans but I want to list the check box `data-cat` to `textarea` which i didn't get by using `return $(this).data('cat');`

Comment: @Sus Hill, it may not work in your fiddle because you have not include jQuery

Comment: @paIasH thank you man...this is helping me....but how can i get the all data from checkbox if multiple checkbox are selected

Comment: You can just append the data to the previous value with  a comma in between like `oldData + ', ' + newData;`.

Comment: @paIasH sorry but i am new to jquery. Can you elaborate your ans. It will be much helpful if you can.

Comment: just check this https://jsfiddle.net/wx2dmLkn/5/. I have explained there.

Comment: What if user's unchecked a checkbox. It is showing the data field. Can it be reduce ?? thanks anyway but if it can be done plz comment

Comment: Yes, that can be done but you atleast give it a try once. simple logic. if unchecked removed that data string from the textarea value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116977/discussion-between-sus-hill-and-pala).

Comment: tried alot but got stuck in this https://jsfiddle.net/sus_hill/wx2dmLkn/12/

Answer (score 0):

As defined at [jQuery data docs](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/), data- attribute is not retrieved, nut you can get it with .data() function

Ex.

`$(this).data('cat')`

Comment: I tried it but got stuck in https://jsfiddle.net/sus_hill/wx2dmLkn/12/  the second textarea